# Can a grenade cause rockets/missiles to explode?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

In the third act of *Avatar: The Way of Water*:

> there is a sequence where Jake Sully sets up a hand grenade in a cluster of unfired rockets stored in a downed helicopter. The grenade goes off, making the helicopter explode.

Is it really possible for a single grenade to make the rockets/aircraft explode?

Comment: What makes you doubt this is possible? Add high energy & fire, make things that are already highly combustible go bang.

Comment: In Ukraine, grenades are currently causing tank ammunition to explode on a regular basis.

Comment: Of course that's 'possible' though that doesn't mean it will happen in any given case.

Further to Tetsujin's and mcalex 2's Comments, why would you doubt that?

If you take the detonator from a grenade and try to use that to fire up your rockets/missiles, it prolly won't work but that's a technical detail.

The full force of a grenade is very likely to set off the rockets/missiles but there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it would.

Essentially military explosives ideally shouldn't explode when dropped or set on fire. You can literally light up C4 and it won't blow up. A 'good' explosive for those sort of uses generally are set off by a smaller charge. I'd refer you to [the wikipedia page, and the section under classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosive#Classification) - your grenade essentially has a small primary explosive charge as a fuse setting off a secondary explosive.  Your rockets generally would have a time or impact fuse (and your exploding grenade would have enough power to set it off) and a large amount of secondary explosive your grenade would set off. Essentially your grenade acts as a primary explosive/detonator for the explosives in the rocket There's likely also some solid propellent that would be set off by heat or pressure.

I don't really want to link war footage here but this isn't any different from the effect that a russian tank would experience from a drone dropped grenade or  being hit in the right place with a HE round, or a grenade dropped on an arms cache. These things  *do* happen in real life.

Answer (score 5):

In *theory*, it's possible. Very unlikely, but still. Most of people I know (or that I knew back in my military days) who had to deal with weapons, and especially explosives, will tell you that storage has to be (and **is**)  done in a way that will prevent dangerous and unwanted ignition of the fuse.

From a [patent about grenade mechanism](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8661979B2/en) and a security device:

> If for any reason one of the pyrotechnic components are activated, unintentionally, such as by extreme heat or by penetration of a bullet or fragment it inevitably causes the grenade to explode. Unintended explosion of a hand grenade can cause fatal injuries. If large numbers of grenades are stored in a single or enclosed storage area and if a grenade unintentionally explodes, the entire storage area could explode and cause great damage.

For the sake of the plot, and keeping in mind that Avatar has "weapons of the future" (read: *much advanced technology and power*), it needs to explode.

On a personal note, and with the little experience I have with grenades, I tend to agree with [Sean Sanders](https://www.quora.com/If-in-any-room-there-are-100-grenades-and-only-1-is-opened-then-will-all-the-grenades-explode-or-only-the-one).

Comment: In practice - https://www.intelligence.gov/evolution-of-espionage/world-war-1/sabotage-subterfuge-and-war/black-tom-island-explodes and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAF_Fauld_explosion . Admittedly they were... bigger booms.

Comment: WWI & WWII. It's all said :) of course this could happen, and even frequently happened, since human kind has been playing with explosive devices. It's still possible, but specialists have been working for decades now to prevent these events. Now, in Belgium and France, you still find a lot of those old bombs from WWII, and they're still dangerous. But it's a 80/90 yo technology.

Comment: *"Unintended explosion of a hand grenade can cause fatal injuries"* – It's interesting that they qualify this statement with "unintended" :-)

Comment: @WillVousden: maybe they should have also emphasize that it's meant to be thrown at someone :)))

Answer (score 3):

It would depend entirely on the technology used in the rocket.

For example, a solid fueled rocket with a plastic explosive warhead wouldn't be detonated by a grenade because they are designed to extremely stable (until you require them not to be), and to be resistant to heat and pressure. They require an electrically operated device that creates a localized high pressure, high speed, shockwave to detonate them.

Simple heat or pressure from a grenade placed next to it won't be enough as grenades are designed to produce a wide shockwave to send shrapnel in all directions.

The fuel in a liquid or gas fueled rocket could hypothetically be detonated if the grenade started a fire but they wouldn't go up in a single large fireball, they would "cook off" individually and would require their fuel to be spilled in order to get the proper oxygen mix to instigate an ignition. You would see them going off individually like

That is of course if the grenade was of the type used our real world modern military and not some kind of science fiction technology.

Comment: There's no purely electrically detonated explosive as far as I know.

Comment: C4, which I'm sure you will have seen in movies and video games is actually a real life explosive and not a make up movie thing. It requires an electrically operated shock wave generator to detonate. It won't detonate if burned and requires substantially more energy than a grenade will generate to detonate.

Comment: C4 uses RDX, as does the composition B in many nato standard grenades. Since its a real explosive, it has a [wikipedia page that says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-4_(explosive)#Detonation)  "Detonation can be initiated only by a shockwave, such as when a detonator inserted into it is fired.[8] " "Electric" igniters are essentially electric matches that detonate a smaller charge that activates the big boom